# zhelpers.h in ZEROMQ compiler error

Tags: c, function, gcc

I recently started learning ZEROMQ and I am stuck somewhere. I tried to run the weather update examples(wuclient.c and wuserver.c) and I get the error below.

```
In file included from wuclient.c:5:0:
zhelpers.h: In function ‘s_sleep’:
zhelpers.h:133:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘nanosleep’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
zhelpers.h: In function ‘s_console’:
zhelpers.h:158:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘time’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
zhelpers.h:159:12: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘localtime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
zhelpers.h:159:26: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
zhelpers.h:161:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strftime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
zhelpers.h:161:5: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strftime’ [enabled by default]
wuclient.c: At top level:
zhelpers.h:60:1: warning: ‘s_send’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
zhelpers.h:67:1: warning: ‘s_sendmore’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
zhelpers.h:75:1: warning: ‘s_dump’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
zhelpers.h:115:1: warning: ‘s_set_id’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
zhelpers.h:125:1: warning: ‘s_sleep’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
zhelpers.h:139:1: warning: ‘s_clock’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
zhelpers.h:156:1: warning: ‘s_console’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
```

The command I used to compile it is: gcc -Wall wuclient.c -o wuclient -L/usr/local/lib -lzmq

And this is the zhelpers.h code here https://github.com/imatix/zguide/blob/master/examples/C/zhelpers.h which is causing the error.

And it was included in this code below:

```
//  Weather update client
//  Connects SUB socket to tcp://localhost:5556
//  Collects weather updates and finds avg temp in zipcode

#include "zhelpers.h"

int main (int argc, char *argv [])
{
    //  Socket to talk to server
    printf ("Collecting updates from weather server...\n");
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *subscriber = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_SUB);
    int rc = zmq_connect (subscriber, "tcp://localhost:5556");
    assert (rc == 0);

    //  Subscribe to zipcode, default is NYC, 10001
    char *filter = (argc > 1)? argv [1]: "10001 ";
    rc = zmq_setsockopt (subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE,
                         filter, strlen (filter));
    assert (rc == 0);

    //  Process 100 updates
    int update_nbr;
    long total_temp = 0;
    for (update_nbr = 0; update_nbr < 100; update_nbr++) {
        char *string = s_recv (subscriber);

        int zipcode, temperature, relhumidity;
        sscanf (string, "%d %d %d",
            &zipcode, &temperature, &relhumidity);
        total_temp += temperature;
        free (string);
    }
    printf ("Average temperature for zipcode '%s' was %dF\n",
        filter, (int) (total_temp / update_nbr));

    zmq_close (subscriber);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

I opened the "zhelpers.h" file and "time.h" was included. So I got confused on why this would happen. Am using Ubuntu 12.04 and please, I am neither an expert in C or ZEROMQ but this software looks like my realistic hope of scaling my thesis hurdle.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Note that these are just warnings and not errors. The compiler will still generate something but it might not work as intended.

The header file "zhelpers.h" includes <sys/time.h> and not <time.h> on Ubuntu. This is most probably incorrect. Remove the conditional in "zhelpers.h" and just include <time.h> on all platforms. This will remove half of the warnings.

The second half of the warnings are related to the fact that there are function definitions in "zhelpers.h". This is very poor coding style but the program should still work.

Comment: You're right.  Those function definitions might make more sense as `static inline` functions.